# Find the probability that the tested computer is defective?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

> A quality control engineer tests the quality of produced computers. Suppose that $10 \%$ of computers have defects, and defects occur independently of each other.

A- Find the probability of exactly $4$ defective computers in a shipment of $20.$

$x\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)\\P(x=4)=\binom{20}{4}(.1)^4(.9)^{16}=.0897
$

B-  Find the probability of at least $3$ defective computers in a shipment of $20$.

$x\sim \text{Binomial}(20,.1,2)=P(x\ge3)=1-P(x\le2)=1-.677=.323$

C- The expected number of defective computers in a shipment of $20$.

$E(x)=np=(20)(.1)=2$

D- Find the probability that the engineer has to test exactly $8$ computers in order to find the first defective computer.

$x\sim\text{Geometric}(.1)=P(8)=(1-.1)^{8-1}*(.1)=.04782969$

E- Find the probability that the tenth computer tested is the fourth defective computer.

$\text{This is where I encounter some difficulty. X:Number of computers to be tested before}\\\text{ finding kth defective.}\\\text{ Hence X can be said to be a random variable following a negative Binomial}\\ \text{Distribution. with parameter p and k. Here k=4,p=.10}\\x\sim \text{NB}(k=4,p=.10)\\P(X)= \binom{x-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{x-k},x=k,k+1.....\\P(X=10)=\binom{9}{3}(.1)^4(.9)^6=.00446\\ \text{ However the textbook states the answer is 0.000053. Where did I make an egregious mistake ?}$

Comment: I can't spot an error in your working for $E$

Comment: Can you please say name of the textbook ?